# Fail2Ban block certain POST requests

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I need to limit POST requests with Fail2ban for this type of log:

```
"POST /subscribers"
```

But not block the requests that are:

```
"POST /subscribers/*" i.e. "POST /subscribers/18"
```

Is it possible to do with fail2ban?
So far I've tried the following jail "subscribers.conf":

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*POST /subscribers
ignoreregex = ^<HOST> -.*POST /subscribers/*
```

But due to the ignoreregex, other requests also being ignored. Any help appreciated!

Jail.local file:

```
[DEFAULT]
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8
mta = mail
destemail = root
sendername = Fail2BanAlerts
findtime = 3600
bantime = 6000
#Send mail on all jails: action = %(action_mwl)s

[subscribers]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = subscribers
logpath  = /var/log/nginx/access.log
maxretry = 3
```

Comment: Are the quotation marks supposed to be there? You have them in failregex but not ignoreregex.

Comment: Hey @mzhaase, nope, I was just trying different options and forgot to remove.

Comment: Try `failregex = ^<HOST> -.*POST /subscribers$`

Comment: Thanks @mzhaase but unfortunately it doesn't work. It still allows the `POST /subscribers`

Comment: Can you post your complete fail2ban configuration, as it pertains to this jail?

Comment: @mzhaase I have added my jail.local file too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58048/discussion-between-mzhaase-and-ilya).

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/799030/fail2ban-regex-for-post-not-firing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/` needs to be escaped in regex.

```
ignoreregex = ^<HOST> -.*POST \/subscribers\/.+ 
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*POST \/subscribers\s.+
```

Will work. What might have happend here is that the regex just ended at the first `/`. I always use one of the many free online regex checkers against the string I am trying to parse.